# Create a class to build a JSON structure where one of its variables is again has all the variables from its own class (C#)

Tags: c#, json

I've been pondering about this for some time and I think I might just be missing an essential basic coding approach to resolve. 
This is what I tried:

```
   class DataSetCommonQuery
    {
        public string @operator;
        public List<DataSetCommonQuery> rules = new List<DataSetCommonQuery>();
    }
```

My expected JSON should be:

```
    {
    "payLoad": {
        "DataSetCommonQuery": {
            "operator": "AND",
            "rules": [{
                    "field": "ENTITY.CIFNumber",
                    "condition": "<>",
                    "value": "3123"
                },
                {
                    "field": "ENTITY.Country",
                    "condition": "LIKE",
                    "value": "USA"
                },
                {
                    "operator": "OR",
                    "rules": [{
                            "field": "ENTITY.FYEMonth",
                            "condition": "=",
                            "value": "May"
                        },
                        {
                            "field": "STATEMENT.ProfitBeforeTax",
                            "condition": ">=",
                            "value": 123123
                        },
                        {
                            "field": "STATEMENT.NetSales",
                            "condition": "<=",
                            "value": 234234
                        },
                        {
                            "field": "STATEMENT.statementdatekey_",
                            "condition": "=",
                            "value": "2019-07-01 12:00:00"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You see there is again **operator** and **rules** inside the **rules**. Any thoughts on how should I be declaring the rules variable to be able to get the expected JSON. I am working to build the JSON on C#.

```
public static DataSetCommonQuery ConvertToJsonObject(string bracketContents)
        {
            DataSetCommonQuery commonQuery = new DataSetCommonQuery();
            string[] operators = splitWithOperator(bracketContents);
            commonQuery.@operator = ReturnOperator(bracketContents);
            string output;
            do
            {
                //bracketContesnts = getWhatsInsideBrackets(bracketContents);
                for (int i = 0; i < splitWithOperator(bracketContents).Length; i++)
                {
                    var jObject = new JObject();
                    if(!checkIfBracketsExists(operators[i]))
                    {
                        List<string> eachCondition = splitEachCondition(operators[i].Trim());
                        eachCondition.Add(operators[i].Replace(eachCondition[0], "").Replace(eachCondition[1], "").Trim());// Substring(operators1[i].IndexOf(eachCondition[0]), (operators1[i].IndexOf(eachCondition[1]) - operators1[i].IndexOf(eachCondition[0]))));
                        jObject.Add("field", eachCondition[0]);
                        jObject.Add("condition", eachCondition[2]);
                        jObject.Add("value", eachCondition[1]);
                    }
                    else if (checkIfBracketsExists(operators[i]))
                    {
                        ConvertToJsonObject(getWhatsInsideBrackets(operators[i]));
                    }
                    commonQuery.rules.Add(jObject); //THIS LINE SHOWS ERROR CAN NOT CONVERT JOBJECT TO DataSetCommonQuery

                }
            } while (checkIfBracketsExists(bracketContents));
            return commonQuery;

        }
```

Comment: You have a class with 2 properties`operator` and `rules` and you want to add both variables to the second property again?`

Comment: Yes @Train. There are further three properties inside the rules[] which I am adding them manually through JObject. Like this: 
 jObject.Add("field", eachCondition[0]);
jObject.Add("condition", eachCondition[2]);
jObject.Add("value", eachCondition[1]);

Comment: Can you show us all your code please?

Comment: @Train Updated the question. Thanks

Comment: seems you've to achieve recursion. May be recursively call method where you've to duplicate the attributes.

Comment: Yes, while I do that. I am not able to achieve adding Operator, Rules[] inside Rules. Instead its adding a field, value condition object to the existing rules. :( @Prany

Comment: ok, it doesn't seem to me a valid json though (in your question), check here - https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I just pasted a partial part of it. Corrected it now. @Prany

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried site converter like this [Json2cssharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: It keeps adding variable rules howmany ever times it appears. Not very useful. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is really a good question, would suggest you to select Newtonsoft.json and do something like this

```
public partial class StackOverFlow
{
    [JsonProperty("payLoad")]
    public PayLoad PayLoad { get; set; }
}

public partial class PayLoad
{
    [JsonProperty("DataSetCommonQuery")]
    public DataSetCommonQuery DataSetCommonQuery { get; set; }
}

public partial class DataSetCommonQuery
{
    [JsonProperty("operator")]
    public string Operator { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rules")]
    public DataSetCommonQueryRule[] Rules { get; set; }
}

public partial class DataSetCommonQueryRule
{
    [JsonProperty("field", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Field { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("condition", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Condition { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("operator", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Operator { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rules", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public RuleRule[] Rules { get; set; }
}

public partial class RuleRule
{
    [JsonProperty("field")]
    public string Field { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("condition")]
    public string Condition { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public Value Value { get; set; }
}

public partial struct Value
{
    public long? Integer;
    public string String;

    public static implicit operator Value(long Integer) => new Value { Integer = Integer };
    public static implicit operator Value(string String) => new Value { String = String };
}

internal static class Converter
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        Converters =
        {
            ValueConverter.Singleton,
            new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
        },
    };
}

internal class ValueConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(Value) || t == typeof(Value?);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.Integer:
                var integerValue = serializer.Deserialize<long>(reader);
                return new Value { Integer = integerValue };
            case JsonToken.String:
            case JsonToken.Date:
                var stringValue = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
                return new Value { String = stringValue };
        }
        throw new Exception();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var value = (Value)untypedValue;
        if (value.Integer != null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.Integer.Value);
            return;
        }
        if (value.String != null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.String);
            return;
        }
        throw new Exception();
    }

    public static readonly ValueConverter Singleton = new ValueConverter();
}
```